# Python clipboard manager?

Tags: python-3.x, clipboardmanager

Where would be a good place start learning to program a clipboard manager in python. i want to be able to copy selected text with a keyboard macro and set it to a slot identified ny the key combo "ctrl+alt+c+1", "ctrl+alt+c+2" storing more than one thing, also so would be got to be able to contaminate on to what is in a slot, if one would want. Any way that is the project i want to write, i write in python 3.2, python 2.7, and java 7. what libraries should i start learning i guess is what i am asking.

Comment: Hey John, Iwas thinking of starting a project of a clipboard manager to Linux. I don't like any of the ones that exist. In windows there's ditto, it's pretty good. Did you start anything?

Comment: i have not yet... been to busy with other stuff to date... its on my todo... it looks to like i should learn C or C++ to do it and maybe learn QT (cross-platform application and UI framework), i am still fairly new to programming and taught myself most of what i know... i dont know yet that i am up to doing the project yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clipboards are framework specific. So a good place would be to select a GUI framework, and look at it's documentation for how to deal with cut and paste.